# I can't get a 4 digits random number in JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop, random, hashset, digits

I'm really new to java. I need to create a method that creates 4 digits random number like 0050, 0100, 9999. So each digit of that number has a limit from 0 to 9!

Here is what I found:

```
package randomNumber;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class RandomNumber {

    public static Set<Integer> getRandom(Set<Integer> setInt){

        setInt = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            Random random = new Random();
            i = random.nextInt(10);     
            setInt.add(i);          
        };

        return setInt;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandom(null));

    }

}
```

So I didn't really understand why in the main I had to set the variable in the getRandom method to "null". 
System.out.println(getRandom()); didn't work out. I'd appreciate if someone coult explain that to me

Anyway I was happy that I had no error messages until I run the code several times. I have either 1 digit number, or 2 digits number and sometimes 3 digits number but it seems that I can never have a 4 digits number whereas I have indicated in my for loop that i < 4. I can't maintain the results to 4 digits. Why?

I'm lost!
If anyone can help me, I would be gratefull. I'm also wondering if I'm using the right method as I need a four digits number and I used a hashset which give me ideally a 4 elements table. Is there another way than a hashset?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why are you passing in a set at all? You can just get rid of that bit. Idk where you got this code from, but it's bad for at least two reasons. You'd be better off just learning how to generate random numbers and write the 5 lines yourself.

Comment: I don't understand why the method takes a parameter at all... Did you write it?

Comment: Why are you using a HashSet? Why give the method a parameter? Is this your own code or is it borrowed code (the unnecessary method parameter and use of HashSet suggests the latter -- that you're misusing borrowed code), and if the latter, from what source?

Comment: Never ever ever (ever!) put `Random random = new Random();` inside a loop.

Comment: Have you noticed that you're stomping on your loop index with the random assignment?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advises! As I said I'm totally new to java. I didn't borrow the code but I had several error messages especialy about parameters missing and for each of them eclipse was suggesting a modification so I just applied what eclipse said but to be honest I didn't really get the meaning of these modifications suggested by eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

`Set` has no order and contains no duplicates - just like in mathematics. `Random` is something what you instantiate once in a program, definitely not in the middle of a loop.

If you want a random number between 0 and 9999, then just generate a random number. Then you can add missing zeroes when printing or converting to string:

```
private static Random rnd=new Random();
public static int getRandom(){
  return rnd.nextInt(10000);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
  int r=getRandom();
  System.out.println("As number: "+r);
  System.out.printf("As 4-digit code, just printing: %04d\n",r);
  String s=String.format("%04d",r);
  System.out.println("As 4-digit code, in separate string: "+s);
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/6Rmc8j (though Ideone cached a 4-digit number, bad luck).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to unpack here but to the actual question:

You're getting varying results because a Set, by design, accepts **unique** values. You're sometimes getting the same integer from the Random so it doesn't get added to the Set because it's already there.

You need an `ArrayList` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a method that creates 4 digits random number like 0050, 0100, 9999

So, none of these values are possible because using a Set will *prevent duplicate numbers* from being added. And the chances you get 4 unique digits out of 10, are fairly small

> didn't really understand why in the main I had to set the variable in the getRandom method to "null". System.out.println(getRandom()); didn't work out

You have a parameter to the method, but you immediately overwrite it. If you want the second way to work, remove the method parameter

> Is there another way than a hashset?

Was there some requirement to use one? If not, `List`, and its subclasses would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

First your questions.

The argument of `getRandom(Set<Integer> setInt)` is not being used. You are creating a new set anyway inside the function. That is why passing `null` still works. So might as well change it to:

```
public static Set<Integer> getRandom(){

    Set<Integer> setInt = new HashSet<>();
```

Your loop is just saying you want to do the loop 4 times. If it happens to generate the same number, the set will omit the duplicate, so you could end up with less.

What you really need is a List there, so that duplicates are not eliminated.

```
public static List<Integer> getRandom(){

  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
```

Also, you should put the `Random` outside. If you are creating a new one each time inside the loop, it will lose its pseudo-random sequence.

Finally, there is a better way if you decide to use Java 8.

```
Random random = new Random();

return Stream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(10))
             .limit(4)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give the `Set` as an argument to `getRandom`.
Create the set in the `getRandom` method and return it.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class RandomNumber {

    public static Set<Integer> getRandom(){

        HashSet<Integer> setInt = new HashSet<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int n = random.nextInt(10);
            setInt.add(n);
        }
        return setInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandom());
    }
}
```